# Ноутбук долго компилирует Angular 7 приложение

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Есть приложение на Angular 7. Работаю в Visual Studio Code. Если сделаю изменение в коде и сохраню, Angular Cli компилирует приложение, и страница в браузере перезагружается. На моем домашнем компьютере, процесс компиляции длится не дольше секунды, но на рабочем ноутбуке может доходить до 10 секунд. Ноутбук конечно слабенький(проц - AMD A4-3305M 2ядра 1.8 МГц, 6гб оперативы). Но при компиляции смотрю в диспетчере задач на потребление ресурсов. Процессор, оперативка и жёсткий диск в этот момент не загружены даже в половину. Что можно сделать что бы ускорить процесс компиляции. Потому что ждать по 10 секунд и более очень неудобно.

Comment: тоже задаюсь этим вопросом, но к сожалению ничего кроме замены процессора не поможет. Сборка осуществляется в однопоточном режиме, следовательно даже если процесс сборки будет монопольно использовать одно и то же ядро он упрётся в частоту ядра, 1.8ГГц (кстати скорее всего гига, а не мега) это довольно мало по современным стандартам.

Comment: к сожалению - такова реальность, низкая тактовая частота, а вебпак работает - цитирую Сокру `Webpack doesn't do any threading or "process"ing.`